# R: Regression of each variable depending on all the others

Tags: r, dataframe, multinomial

In `R`, I have the following `data.frame`:

```
df <- data.frame(var1,var2,var3)
```

I would like to fit a regression function, like `multinom`, for each variable with respect to the others, without using the variable names explicitely. In other words, I would like to obtain this result:

```
fit1 <- multinom(var1 ~ ., data=df)
fit2 <- multinom(var2 ~ ., data=df)
fit3 <- multinom(var3 ~ ., data=df)
```

But in a for loop, without using the variable names (so that I can use the same code for any `data.frame`). Something similar to this:

```
for (i in colnames(df))
{
  fit[i] <- lm(i ~ ., data=df)
}
```

(This code does not work.)

Maybe my question is trivial, but I have no idea on how to proceed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add an extra step to build the formula object using string operation

```
fit <- vector(mode = "list", length = ncol(df))
for (i in colnames(df)) {
    fm <- as.formula(paste0(i, " ~ ."))
    fit[[i]] <- lm(fm, data = df)
}
```